# Series expression of $\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Hi: I am trying to find a series expression for the integral:
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} dx$$
and use it to prove:
$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \log 2$$

I have already discovered that $\log 2$ is the value of the integral after evaluating it with the usual tools. I have not been able to find a series expression for the integral, as its Taylor series seems to behave badly.

Any hint would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the geometric series and interchange the order of summation and integration.

Comment: $$\dfrac{e^{-x}}{1 + e^{-x}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n - 1} e^{-n x}$$

Comment: @Essaidi Thank you, I now see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do the substitution $e^{-x}=t$ and $-e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$, then your integral becomes\begin{align}-\int_1^0\frac1{1+t}\,\mathrm dt&=\int_0^1\frac1{1+t}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^11-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots\,\mathrm dt\\&=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: Thank you but I already know how to solve the integral, I want to derive a series expansion for it.

Comment: Sure. Sorry about that. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you! I will accept your answer when the system lets me do it.